# removing spaces between numbers with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

am making a form validation, and i need to replace all spaces in the phone input, there for i created this regexp that seems not to be working for reasons i don't know
[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uI5hJ3/1)
this is the code i tried : `/(\d)[().\-\s]+(\d)/g`
i expect to get : `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` become `1234567`
note that i can't use `element.val().replace(/\s/g,'')` because the input has other text that will be damaged with this action
so it got to be my code, and if it has a problem i must sort it out
i wish to know more why the regexp is returning the first match only even if i have the `g` modifier, if anyone could explain me that, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
var str = "hello world 1 2 3 4 5 6 hello world";
var re = /(\d)\s+(?=\d)/g;
str.replace(re, '$1');
```

Output

```
"hello world 123456 hello world"
```

Visualization of regexp

[image: /(\d)\s+(?=\d)/g]